# Check if all text inputs are empty, show alert with for if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, input

beginner here. I'm trying to use a conditional to check whether if the text inputs have been filled out, otherwise if empty, prompt an alert but it doesn't appear to do anything? Is my JS poorly laid out? Here is my jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/rtomino/4ywq9n3n/2/

Thank you!!

```
<div>
    <label for="cand1">Candidate 1</label>
    <input class="candidate" id="cand1" placeholder="Candidate">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="cand2">Candidate 2</label>
    <input class="candidate" id="cand2" placeholder="Candidate">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="cand3">Candidate 3</label>
    <input class="candidate" id="cand3" placeholder="Candidate">
</div>
```

The JS

```
function candidateNames() {
   var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
   var result = [];
 for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1 ) {
   result[i] = inputs[i].value;

  if (inputs === '' || null || 0) {
      alert('Need to fill inputs');
  }  
}
  document.getElementById("candidateName1").innerHTML = result[0];
  document.getElementById("candidateName2").innerHTML = result[1];
  document.getElementById("candidateName3").innerHTML = result[2];
}
```

Comment: You're testing if inputs === '' || null || etc.... Are you sure you're checking the right variable?  inputs is an array.. It's probably not null.  Are you looking to see if inputs[i].value === '' || null || etc?

Comment: Besides what @Aaron mentions, you can't compare a variable to multiple values like that. You'd need to compare something to `''`, then compare that same thing to `null`, the compare the same thing to `0`. Note, however, that the value of an input is always a string, and thus will never be `null` or `0` (it might be `"0"` however).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if you inputs array is empty and not if the current input's value is empty.

See my inline comments.

```
function candidateNames() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var result = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1 ) {
      result[i] = inputs[i].value;

      if (inputs[i].value == '') { // check if value is empty
          alert('Need to fill inputs');
          return; // stop the function
      }

}
    document.getElementById("candidateName1").innerHTML = result[0];
    document.getElementById("candidateName2").innerHTML = result[1];
    document.getElementById("candidateName3").innerHTML = result[2];
}

//Event listener to calculate button to call all above functions
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", calculateVotes, false);

function calculateVotes() {
  candidateNames();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for (inputs === '' || null || 0), which is wrong as inputs is an array, you need to do something like this:

```
function candidateNames() {console.log('here');
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var result = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1 ) {
      result[i] = inputs[i].value;

      if (results[i] === '' || null || 0) {
          alert('Need to fill inputs');
      }

}
    document.getElementById("candidateName1").innerHTML = result[0];
    document.getElementById("candidateName2").innerHTML = result[1];
    document.getElementById("candidateName3").innerHTML = result[2];
}
```